# XCOPY /d - does it support time as well as date?

Tags: windows-xp, cmd, command-line-interface, datetime-format, xcopy

`XCOPY /d` is documented to take a date in the form dd-mm-yyyy but I can't find any mention of similar support for time.

Is there (or a workaround even) or do I have to download another command line tool for winxp?

Comment: btw I know about the win xp download packs that provide other tools such as forfile. I would prefer a solution that works with what comes in the xp box i.e. command extensions and nothing more.

Comment: I'd also like to know why 2 people think batch scripts are off topic...

Comment: with 'for /f'  iteration through files and '%~ti' you can extract time creation and compare it to a given one to decide if file should be copied http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntfor.php#FOR_F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to include time as a criteria in XCOPY. This is true for ROBOCOPY as well, even though it has many more configuration options than XCOPY.

The XXCOPY application will do what you ask -- but as you say, this costs money (for commercial uses, anyway).

http://www.xxcopy.com/xxtb_001.htm - search for "/DA:".